# Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies - searching in wrong folder?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, reference, .net-assembly

My code was working and out of no where I am starting to get this:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Syncfusion.SfGrid.WPF, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89' or
> one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
>
> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Syncfusion.SfGrid.WPF, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89' or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I ran fugslovw as recommended from other posts but cannot figure out how to solve this. It seems the assembly protocol is looking for Syncfusion.SfGrid.WPF.dll in the wrong directory. Syncfusion.SfGrid.WPF.dll is in the /bin/Debug folder so why isnt it searching there similar to other assemblies it found? I got this dll from nuget package and they are the same version accross my entire project. I also tried cleaning my solution. Any hints please? I have attached the two failing logs [here](https://pastebin.pl/view/7797a488) and [here](https://pastebin.pl/view/fdbf5576). An example of a successful log which I expect is [here](https://pastebin.pl/view/17ed4cdf)

Comment: It seems your program is running from `C:\Program Files\Computers and Structures\ETABS 19`. You need to copy all required assemblies into this directory.

Comment: My program is a plugin attached to ETABS. My plugin worked fine without copying any assemblies until yesterday so something must have changed. Why does the example of the successful log look into bin folder while this one doesnt? What controls this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the application (ETABS) loads your DLL with Assembly.LoadFrom, therefore resolving the dependencies works at this point in time.

When later WPF tries to load additional dependencies, it does not know about the  location of your plugin and thus does not consider your bin directory.

We had a similar problem with a plugin architecture and solved it by pre-loading all required depedencies before the WPF control is created, e.g. by

```
_ = new AnyTypeFromTheAssembly();
```

Comment: I dont understand this, I am new to this. Can you provide a simple example of what youre saying. My plugin worked totally fine until suddenly I am getting this error which is what is confusing me. For some other parts of the plugin it searches in the bin folder but for this specific dll its searching within the ETABS folder instead (while it was searching in bin previously?) I am using Prism and the main module is working but I get this issue when loading another module with the same .dll

Comment: I think what I'm trying to say is why another dll is successful and this isnt? See the attached successful log

Comment: I am using Prism to structure my plug-in. The main module uses Syncfusion.SfGrid.WPF.dll and it's loaded fine in that window. When I try to launch another modu,e

Comment: This depends on how the host application loads the plugin. I don't know the internals of ETABS, but maybe during the initial load of the plugin DLL, ETABS successfully resolves referenced DLLs also from the Plugin directory while when WPF loads a DLL later, this resolution is no longer in place.

Comment: But the initial loading of the plugin does contain WPF components which utilize this dll. Also do you know what might of caused it suddenly to not work? Is there a config file I should look into. Is there a way to specify the dll location for the second module so it doesnt search in another folder?

Comment: Also could you explain your fix more? Do you mean you are creating an object (a window for example assuming thats the dll) that uses this dll before the WPF control is created to force the plugin to load the dll?

Comment: I meant: create an object of any class that is implemented in the DLL. For Syncfusion.SfGrid.WPF, this could e.g. be `new Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Grid.SfDataGrid()`. This will force the DLL to load.

Comment: Thank you. I'll test that and let you know how it goes. Selected you as the solution. :)

Comment: Thanks so much. That fixed it. Since you seem experienced with plugins, do you usually lump all your .dll's into one for easier deployment?